# Why is tkinter using a fill colour of black instead of the colour I specify?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I just started learning `tkinter` by drawing a Mandelbrot set.

I specify a fill colour as the string `'#0074bf'`, but it is rendered as `black`.   Why is the kwarg ignored in the call `c.create_oval(x, y, x, y, fill = '#0074bf')`?

```
from tkinter import *

# Some globals
SIZE = 4
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600
ratio = (WIDTH / SIZE, HEIGHT / SIZE)
zmin = -SIZE / 2 - (SIZE / 2) * 1j
zmax = SIZE / 2 + (SIZE / 2) * 1j
ESCAPE_RADIUS = 4
max_iterations = 256

# Create the window with Canvas
master = Tk()
c = Canvas(master, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
c.pack()

# Define a function to iterate; here, the classic Mandelbrot set function, z -> z^2 + c
f =  lambda z, c : z * z + c

def iterate(pixel):
    """
    Given a pixel (as a complex number x + iy) return the
    number of iterations it takes to escape,
    or the final count if it doesn't.
    """
    z0 = px_to_cx(pixel)
    z = z0
    num_iterations = 0
    while abs(z) < ESCAPE_RADIUS and num_iterations < max_iterations:
        z = f(z, z0)
        num_iterations += 1
    return num_iterations - 1

def px_to_cx(pixel):
    return (pixel.real - WIDTH / 2) / ratio[0] + ((pixel.imag - HEIGHT / 2) / ratio[1]) * 1j

for y in range(HEIGHT):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        num = iterate(x + y * 1j)
        if  num < max_iterations / 2:
            # Here, the fill argument I supply seems to be ignored:
            c.create_oval(x, y, x, y, fill = '#0074bf')

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your 1-pixel ovals are showing only their outline color, which defaults to black - they're simply not big enough to have any visible pixels of the fill color.  Add `width=0` to get rid of the outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an oval one pixel wide and one pixel tall. What you see is the color of the oval outline. With only one pixel there isn't enough space to draw both the outline and an interior.

You can either set the `outline` attribute to the same color as the fill color, or set the outline width (`width` attribute) to zero.

Here is an example that shows two different blocks of 1-pixel ovals. One has the default outline width of one, and the other explicitly sets the outline width to zero. Notice in the first you're seeing the outline color, and in the second you're seeing the fill color.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, background="black")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, outline="red", fill="green")

for x in range(100, 200):
    for y in range(100, 200):
        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, outline="red", fill="green", width=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: The first method works - setting outline to the same as the fill colour - but if instead I pass 'width=0` the window opens but nothing is rendered.

I wish I could find the authoritative documentation about Tkinter for Python 3 with all parameters of all methods explained...

Comment: @John: the canonical documentation is written for tcl/tk, but it's easy to translate to python. This documentation is the most accurate on the internet. http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm

Comment: Thanks @Brian Oakley.   That's helpful. :)